# Django model's __str__ with seperate fields

Tags: python, django

I have a model that return's a financial year and a description. Currently the attributes are combined into one value as one field.

[image]

As you can see, the year *2021* and description *test*. I can click on the field which brings me to the details page.

My code:

```
    class Meta:
    ordering = ['description', 'accounting_year', 'swift_code']
    verbose_name_plural = "Extractions"

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.accounting_year} {self.description}'
```

What I would like to achieve, but can't figure out nor find it online is to split the two fields into separate columns. Thus, *2021* as a column and *test* as a column.

Furthermore, I would like to be able to sort or even filter, because one of the fields is extraction date. Would be great that an admin user could changed the order from newest to oldest and vice versa of just filter on name or date. Any documentation on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

In your apps/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from yourapp.models import Extraction

class ExtractionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['accounting_year', 'description']


admin.site.register(Extractions, ExtractionAdmin)
```

for filter refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal

for sorting refer
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.sortable_by

Comment: What if I wanted to add another attribute, but from a different model?